# Sorting django-tagging results

Tags: python, django, tagging, django-tagging

I'm retrieving a set of DIFFERENT (of different class/model) objects with

```
items = tagging.models.TaggedItem.objects.distinct().filter(tag__name__in=tagslist)
```

all these objects necessarily have pub_date field, and I'd like to sort them by that field.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Igor

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I misunderstood the question. You'll need to order them using regular python code as you won't be able to refer back to the original object for order_by

As items is a QuerySet, you can chain the `order_by()` call onto your `filter()` call like so:

```
items = tagging.models.TaggedItem.objects.distinct().filter(tag__name__in=tagslist).order_by(pub_date)
```

Comment: This would be an attempt to sort the TAGS by pub_date, not the objects they are tagging. Naturally, this replies with:

`Cannot resolve keyword 'pub_date' into field. Choices are: content_type, id, object_id, tag`

What I need is to do something like 

`for item1, item2 in items:
        compare item.object.pub_date`

but of course do it the proper way without breaking the iterator structure.
sorry about the pseudo-python

Comment: pub_date would only be available on object (generic relation on Tag model) which you can't use in a query or in a order by (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3967871/188955) you probably need to do the ordering in python.

Comment: James, thanks a lot, that sounds reasonable. Would you also know if there's a way to stick the 'manual' ordering into the iterator without turning it into an array? I tried using `sorted` method, but it's confusing and actually doesn't seem to affect the end result.

Comment: what did you try? sorted(items, key=lambda x: x.object.pub_date) should work

Comment: Yes. This way worked, but only I have re-read the manual )))

If anyone wants to understand the various sorting options, do check the following:

http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Thanks JamesO ))